# Why does time evolution preserve the norm of a wavefunction?

Tags: hilbert-space, schroedinger-equation, probability, time-evolution, unitarity

I saw an awesome derivation of Schrodinger's equation on Wikipedia. Part of it relies on:

> Since time-evolution must preserve the norm of the wave-function, it follows that $U(t', t)$ must be a member of the unitary group of operators acting on wave-functions, where $\Psi(t') = U(t', t)\Psi(t)$

So, the question is: Why should time evolution preserve the norm of a wave-function?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/169936/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The norm of the wavefunction gives the probability that the particle still exists *at all*. So the norm of the wavefunction changing implies that particles can either be created or destroyed.

In ordinary, non-relativistic quantum mechanics, particle number is a conserved quantity. Particles can neither be created or destroyed, and so the norm of the wavefunction stays constant.

Comment: When it is said that unitary operators preserve norm of a function, do they preserve $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |\Psi(x, y, z, t)|^2 dx dy dz$$ or $$|\Psi(x, y, z, t)|$$ Because I think you are talking about the first, while norm means the second

Comment: @PhyEnthusiast The norm is not $\int\left|\Psi\right|d^3x$, but $\sqrt{\int\left|\Psi\right|^2d^3x}$. So conserving the first is the same as conserving the norm.

Comment: But $\sqrt{|\Psi|^2 d^3 x}$ is not the same as $|\Psi|$, is it? So, which is called the norm

Comment: They preserve the first one. The norm-squared is your first expression, and the square root of the first expression is called the norm.

Comment: They are not the same, no. $\sqrt{\int\left|\Psi\right|^2d^3x}$ is the norm. $\int\left|\Psi\right|d^3x$ isn't particularly meaningful, physically.

Comment: @PhyEnthusiast The issue is that there are infinitely many different ways to define a 'norm'. Chris is talking about the physically meaningful one.

Comment: @knzhou Thnx. I get it now

Answer (score 2):

If you look for a probability interpretation of QM, you get a continuity equation of the form $$\partial_{t}\rho+ \vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{j}=0,$$ where $$\rho\left(\vec{x},t\right)\equiv\psi^*\left(\vec{x},t\right)\psi\left(\vec{x},t\right)$$ and $$\vec{j}\equiv\frac{\hbar}{2im}\left(\psi^*\vec{\nabla}\psi -
 \psi\vec{\nabla}\psi^*\right).$$ Integrating the continuity equation over a finite volume $V$ and using the [divergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem), you can find $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\int_V \mathrm{d}^3x\psi^*\psi=-\frac{\hbar}{2im}\int_\sigma \mathrm{d}\sigma\left(\psi^*\partial_n\psi-\psi\partial_n \psi^*\right),$$ where $\sigma\equiv\partial V$ is the smooth boundary surface of $V$ and $\partial_n\left(\cdot\right)$ indicates the normal derivative (directional derivative taken in the direction normal to the surface). If you let the volume $V$ tend to the whole space, $\mathbb{R}^3$, since your wavefunction is in the Hilbert space $\mathscr{L}^2\left(\mathbb{R}^3\right)$, last equation becomes $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\int_V \mathrm{d}^3x\psi^*\psi\equiv\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left|\psi\left(\vec{x},t\right)\right|^2=0,$$ so you can see that the preservation in time of the norm of the wavefunction is required in order to get a probability interpretation of the theory.

Note that, at this level, you're not allowing decays, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Schrodinger's equation evolved in order to solve the problems that arose for small dimensions: photoelectric effect, spectra of hydrogen modeled by the Bohr model, black body radiation, etc. It is a mathematical model, to start with successful in predicting the decay spectra.

I evolved into a theory, quantum mechanics, which instead of determining positions at time t, gives the probability of finding a particle at time t. The probability given by the complex conjugate squared of the wavefunction given by the Schrodinger equation to start with.

Probability should always be bounded by 0 and 1, by construction.

Comment: It will depend on the solution of the equation. In interference experiments there exist interferences in time too. see my answer here  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/388555/double-slit-experiment-temporal-behaviour/388566#388566